# Как правильно сделать переопределение своей функции события? C++

Tags: c++, ооп, virtual

Допустим есть собственный базовый класс, который имеет метод eventHandler(), обрабатывающий все возможные события и в соответствии с типом события вызывающий ту или иную функцию события. Например, при клике вызывает onClick().

Вопрос: Если я захочу, чтобы наследники-классы могли как переопределять, так и не переопределять функции события, то как это реализовать? Если сделать базовый класс абстрактным, а функции событий - чистыми виртуальными, то мы заставим обязательно определить логику для функций событий. Что делать в таком случае? Просто определить функцию событий так, чтобы они "ничего не делала"? Или вообще не писать определение для функции?

Comment: Просто определить функцию событий так, чтобы они "ничего не делала"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Спасибо за ответ. А что будет, если в родительском классе вообще не определять функцию? Просто сделать ее прототип?

Comment: если будет только "прототип", без тела, то весь класс будет абстрактным. А создать экземпляр абстрактного класса (по крайней мере официальными способами) нельзя.